# Using Xsd.exe for a Scheme that is in Multiple XSD Files

Tags: .net, xsd

How do I create a .CS file using XSD.exe where I have 4 - 5 XSD files each pointing to one. i.e a Complex tyoe and simple types?.

Answer (score 1):

xsd.exe takes in a list of XML Schema files, followed by options. An xsd.exe command line example for multiple XSD files is shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896602/the-minoccurs-attribute-cannot-be-present/8944124#8944124). For example, to generate classes:

```
xsd.exe file1.xsd file2.xsd file3.xsd file4.xsd file5.xsd /c
```